# Run NGINX with subdomains

Tags: nginx, routes, subdomain

I want to run nginx with two different subdomains and let them point to different roots. Therefore I split up the two server blocks into files, named them accordingly and set it up like down below. When I disable one of them both subdomains point to the same root so they are working for themselves, but the division between sub1 and sub2 is not working. It just uses the file it finds first for both subdomains.

sub1.example.de

```
server {
        server_name sub1.example.de;
        root /var/www/wordpress/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        location ~\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;



                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
                fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
                fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location /wordpress/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;
        }
}
```

sub2.example.de

```
server {
        server_name sub2.example.de;
        root /var/www/phpmyadmin/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        location ~\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }


}
```

my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024 ;

}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        map $scheme $server_https {
                default off;
                https on;
        }

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Do you have something in front of this server? The `server_name` is not matching the request, so the first server block is being used as default.

Comment: @RichardSmith do you mean in this file or somewhere in nginx.config or similar?